# How do I put input to a variable in a template?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a script that requires user input to run another script. The read host asks the user what it wants to do, which gets sent to the variable, but I want the users to only type the name without the extension of the file .(this part here).ps1.

```
Read-Host -Prompt "hello" | set-variable test = ".\"*".ps1"
Invoke-expression $test
```

So, if I typed "test" it would run .\test.ps1
I'm not really familiar with pipe, but I think it runs the input through the command after the symbol.

Comment: Set-Variable does not support pipe.
try: `Set-Variable -Name "test" -Value ".\$(Read-Host -Prompt "Hallo").ps1"`

Comment: Please consider the security impact of running any PowerShell code the user types. Could the user delete a directory or format a disk?

Comment: I wrote a little template engine that combines data in a csv file with a template containing variables.  You can see it at (my repository)[www.github.com/dcressey/Expand-csv]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the output from `Read-Host` to a variable and then construct the final string from that:

```
# request script file base name from user
$basename = Read-Host -Prompt "hello"

# invoke the target script file
& ".\${basename}.ps1"
```